# Communication between two microcontrollers with independent Vcc powers

Tags: microcontroller, spi, interface

I need to send signals from one STM32 to another, while each has its own power source (each a separate battery pack). both units operate with the same voltage level (3.3 V) but @ different core clock (receiver 168MHz vs sender 36MHz)
Can I use SPI ? if not what should/can I do?
any method to perform a single-directed data transfer is ok.
Data length is a few bytes, every few seconds.

EDIT :
added some quasi-diagrams:

first MCU, powered from the first 9V battery pack:
[image: First MCU]

Second MCU, from another 9V battery pack:
[image: Second MCU]

EDIT2 : the switching regulators are 2596-3.3V, the 5V versions in the schematics are actually 3.3 V

Comment: I think the main argument in the comments below is about whether the galvanic isolation is important to you? If not, just ignore my answer.

Comment: @tobalt it actually is important. I can't make them same-grounded. I should worry about the batteries being at different levels ? (I mean could the communication errors happen if the batteries of both MCUs are exactly in equal voltage levels ?)

Comment: In this case, please ignore Drew's answer instead to avoid trouble lol..Sorry for confusions

Comment: Please show a wiring diagram of how the MCUs are connected to each other, not just in terms of SPI but where their power supplies come from and how else they might connect to each other (whatever the ground return path might be).

Comment: The signal level will be approximately the supply rail voltage of the master (3.3V). If this voltage exceeds the rail voltage of the receiver by more than ~0.7V current may flow through protection diodes in the receiving MCU, parasitically powering it (which you don't want). If both devices are running at 3.3V and in regulation, that will not happen.

Comment: Thanks all. maybe my question was not clear enough without pictures, (though the text is all the diagrams show). anyway i'll go with optocouplers. does it mean the optocouplers' outputs (transistor side) always should be connected to the power-rail of the receiver of the signal. right?

Comment: The `9V_BATTERY_A_NEG` and `9V_BATTERY_B_NEG` are just arbitrary labels to us. Can you show how they, in turn, connect? Do we take it for granted that there is no connection at all between them, they are fully isolated? Does it matter for anything else that they remain isolated (is there a hot-swap switch between the two or something? why use two batteries at all when one will do, etc.)? Are these on the same board, separate, or what, is there a cable between them?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, they're two battery packs, with independent leads (each + and -). not connected. actually the MCUs are both on the same board, but I want the smaller MCU (the one only sending data) to be totally isolated from everything on the board. it acts as simple supervisor for other components on the board. (sequential power up, temperature controls, some other malfunction detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! You cannot use any galvanic interface, like SPI, between two galvanically disconnected circuits. Both circuits could be at vastly different common-mode voltages and thus wouldn't agree on the signal levels. To make that work you also need to link the grounds galvanically, which then causes them to be not galvanically isolated anymore.

If you must use SPI and must maintain isolation, you could run it across a digital isolator with enough signal bandwidth capability, e.g. 50 Mbit/s. Simple optocouplers are too slow for any reasonable SPI speed.

If you only need to transmit a few bytes per second, a simple optocoupler should suffice.

Comment: Why not connect the grounds together? Need a signal return anyway...

Comment: @JohnDoty sure they can. All I'm saying is that connecting the grounds is mandatory, as you rightfully say. And this will remove the isolation obviously, which is the OP's thing to judge if they want it or not.

Comment: What is wrong/misleading in this answer to justify downvoting it? I think the info is accurate and relevant.

Comment: I downvoted you. It's blatantly incorrect. They are not galvanically isolated, because you can connect them with a ground wire.

Comment: @Drew of course, they are galvanically isolated, before you add the galvanic link.

Comment: @tobalt OP hasn't provided any information precluding that.

Comment: Neither of you have answered a clearly-defined question, I'd just as well downvote both of them for hastiness. Perhaps OP will provide context that proves one of these correct, I don't know.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't think it was hasty, because I clearly cover both cases in my answer: That with isolation being irrelevant and with isolation being importand

Comment: @TimWilliams How have I not answered his question? Can he use spi between the devices? Answer, yes, with a ground connection. Unless there are additional complications which have not been stated, that is the objectively correct answer.

Comment: @Drew Consider the headline, "with separate VCC powers" -- what if there's backfeed from one into the other via ESD clamp diodes? Are the MCUs depower-tolerant? (They are, actually, but does OP know this?) Are they... wait, 5V?! Oh dear...

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with doing that. Simply pass the ground and datalines between the devices.

The only complication is if BOTH of the devices are connected to ground by separate cables. This creates a ground loop. This is not automatically a problem. BUT, if there's a ground level difference between the devices, it can cause excessive current in the signal ground wire, and/or interfere with the data transmission. In that case you would want some kind of galvanic isolation like an optocoupler.

Ground level differences can be caused by either device drawing a lot of current, or just some other device dumping a lot of current into a ground shared by one of the devices.

SPI should work fine, or UART, or i2c.

Interference is more likely when passing a signal from device to device like this, so you may want to implement a CRC check.

Comment: Ground loops are vastly overrated. Just have a ground for each signal

Comment: Ground loops are also irrelevant to the point you are making of the large ground currents. And the OP insist on isolation, so adding a ground wire is not an option apparently.

Comment: @tobalt They are relevant, because they're the only practical reason to use galvanic isolation.

Comment: @JohnDoty How do you figure? Ground loops are an undesirable condition that can occur even if every signal has a dedicated ground.

Comment: @Drew I have seen many designs fail because inexperienced designers tried to avoid "ground loops". Unless you are into detailed electromagnetic design, it is usually much better to connect subsystems together with a low impedance network of multiple grounds, ideally on ground per signal, kept as close as possible to it. "Let ground abound". Missing grounds are almost always trouble: extras, not so much. There are special cases where this is not true, but they are relatively rare.

Comment: @JohnDoty I'm not suggesting omitting any grounds. Consider the classic example of a ground loop: A stereo receiver connected to a speaker amplifier across the room via a 2 wire standard line audio cable. Unless one of the 2 devices has galvanic isolation (such as an audio transformer), you will get a hum in the signal. Even though both devices have burly ground wires connecting to the outlet, along with a ground wire in the audio cable. I think maybe you're confused about the definition of ground loop.

Comment: @Drew A special case having very little to do with SPI between battery operated devices.

Comment: @JohnDoty It occurs to varying degrees any time you connect 2 devices with a cable which have their own wall power supplies. It's actually fairly common. That's just an easy to observe example.

Comment: @Drew But that isn't the situation here. It's unusual for digital devices to have this problem unless their interconnects don't include adequate grounding. Even for low level analog, good coax cable can largely prevent problems.

Comment: @JohnDoty I wouldn't be so quick to assume: 1. we don't know how long the cable might be, and it could indeed be long enough that even (shield resistance) * (ground loop current) = enough voltage drop to violate logic thresholds; 2. there are several prominent voices on here for example, that advocate cutting shield ground on one side, even when normal-mode signals are involved: even if such violation doesn't occur statically, the introduction of common-mode noise causes the same problem at AC. Adequate grounding is indeed the (RF) solution, but it can be difficult for that truth to be heard.

Comment: @TimWilliams All I can say is that over 50 years, I've seen many designers, ranging from beginning students to spacecraft system engineers, get into trouble removing grounds because "ground loops are bad". Extra grounds are not nearly so hazardous.